# Inkscape draw silhouette

Tags: vector, inkscape, art

I'm new to vector art in general and for practice i'm trying to create a black/white fox head. What is the procedure/steps to draw a picture alike the image below in Inkscape? I tried doing it in many ways, like with triangles and circles and the bezier pen but couldn't manage to make it. I could use some tips to learn making different and complex shapes better in Inkscape too.

[image: Fox silhouette]

And this is what i've done so far:

[image: My attempt]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post what have you tried, where you failed? Otherwise there are many ways to do this same image and we can't help you solve your problem - check [ask] to learn how to write a good question

Comment: Hi, i deleted the image but i basically used a triangle in the middle with smooth edges, a circle on top as the head and used bezier pen to draw the ears and the white part of the eyes.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Rick! Can you tell us something more about your efforts? Your questions seems similar to this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92230/outlining-a-group-of-movable-objects-in-inkscape

Comment: I edited the post and added a new image to show what i've done. I need some tips on the procedure to help me make something alike the first image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shape is perhaps too complex to be replicated by combining simple elementary shapes such as triangles and circles. If you want to replicate it, use the pen tool and draw bezier curves. Have a locked reference image in the bottom. Start by clicking only to make a polygon:

[image]

NOTE: There's no need to draw more than a half, because you can duplicate the result in some phase and flip it.

Then with the node tool click the nodes , hold Shift and drag the handles out of the nodes:

[image]

Here the shape is duplicated, the copy is flipped, moved to its place and an union has been made.

[image]

Have enough point snapping options on to make the copy to snap easily.

Hopefully this is enough for a start.